# How get Delivery SMS for bulk SMS

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sms, bulk

I have SMSReceiver Class extends `BroadcastReceiver` . How use `registerReceiver()` and `unregisterReceiver()` in background for deliver Bulk SMS.

I want when close app running SMSReceiver for get deliveries and save deliveries to data base.

```
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private Realm realm;
private static final String ACTION_SMS_DELIVERED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
private String number, name;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    number = intent.getStringExtra("number");
    name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
    if (ACTION_SMS_DELIVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) {

        switch (getResultCode()) {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                try {
                   realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
                   GroupsModel toEdit = realm.where(GroupsModel.class)
                           .equalTo("GroupName", name)
                           .equalTo("Tell", number)
                           .equalTo("Status", false).findFirst();
                   if (toEdit.getStatus() == false) {
                       realm.beginTransaction();
                       toEdit.setStatus(true);
                       realm.commitTransaction();

                   }
                   realm.close();
                  //  Toast.makeText(context, name + number,
                  //          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("a", e.toString());
                }
                break;

            case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                Toast.makeText(context, "error",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```